# Deploy Magento 2(PHP) on heroku

Tags: php, heroku, magento, salesforce, magento2

I want to deploy a Magento 2 project on Heroku as my requirement consists of the integration of Magento 2 with Salesforce. I am not sure if Heroku and Magento 2 are compatible for deploying a larger application like Amazon and Flipkart.

Initially, there will be around 10k users and it will gradually increase. Will Heroku be able to host the Magento 2 Application? I know I will have to get paid subscriptions and all on Heroku and I am okay with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your own version of Magento on Heroku in seconds using the Heroku button below:

Deploy

You can see a live demo at Heroku Magento MySQL

Heroku provides the tools and services you need to build and deploy customer-facing applications without having to worry about infrastructure.

https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/ju3tin/magento2

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! I can't upvote the answer as I don't have reputations but Thanks a lot